# com.facebook.sdk error 2 on login for some users using FBLoginView

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have been getting the infamous com.facebook.sdk error 2 for some users when trying to login to an app I'm working on.

- This error doesn't happen to everyone, only to certain (and what
  seems to be unrelated users).
- The app is switched off in their (users who are getting the error) settings->facebook, but switching it ON
  doesn't solve the problem and the com.facebook.sdk error 2 is still
  persistent, not allowing login.
- The solution is (as mentioned in some
  other posts), to go to settings->Facebook-> Delete account.

This is **all** the code i have for the FBLoginView

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"user_friends",@"email"];
loginView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height-80);
loginView.delegate = self;
```

- When I don't ask for those permission (don't set readPermissions), the login works fine for users that were experiencing errors, but this prohibits users taking advantage of features of the FB framework. From my understanding, these are the 3 basis permissions and should work for everyone without having my app submitted to the FB AppCenter.

My app is live (out of sandbox mode), bundle name, appID match in my project. Any idea to what I'm doing wrong, thing I should check to solve this? I have tried almost everything and am feeling quite hopeless already. Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to cause the problem was the permission `public_profile`. Once I removed it, it worked fine. Not sure if this has something to do with the sdk version...but apparently it does. Gluck!